# Accessing GenericTypeParameters of generic type in C#

Tags: c#, generics, types

I want to generate the name of the generic class with their declared parameter names. For example if I have generic class and instantiated ones like shown below I want to print `"MyClass<P1,M>"`.

```
class MyClass<P1, M1> {}
// ... some code removed here
var myInstance = new MyClass<int,string>();
```

Now I get my type information for `myInstance` and then generic type definition like this:

```
// MyClass<int,string> type info here
var type = myInstance.GetType();
 // MyClass<P1, M1> type info here
var genericType = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
```

Debugger shows `genericType` property GenericTypeParameters with all parameter names and type info. However I cannot access that collection from my C# code and casting `genericType` to System.RuntimeType class does not work because RuntimeType is internal.

So is there a way to access GenericTypeParameters property somehow or am I SOL here?
Environment VS2015, .NET 4.6.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're just looking for [`Type.GetGenericArguments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments), which you should call on `genericType` rather than `type` - at that point, the type "arguments" are really the type *parameters* because it's an open type.

Sample (using `Dictionary<,>` for simplicity):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        var type = dictionary.GetType();
        var genericType = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        foreach (var typeArgument in genericType.GetGenericArguments())
        {
            // TKey, then TValue
            Console.WriteLine(typeArgument);
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully with that information you can work out the string formatting etc yourself.

Comment: @MichaelLiu: Ah, yes - whoops, misread. Will delete, edit and then undelete.

Comment: Awesome! Pretty much GetGenericArguments() returns GenericTypeParameters property that I can see in debugger. Confusion gone for now.